# Identifying different authentication types in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

how to differentiate between email auth and phone auth in android studio?
the code below is not working

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d("bantai", "onStart: ");
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber()!=null){
            String temp = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
            Log.d("bantai", "onStart: phonenumber " + temp +" <-");
            startActivity(new Intent(EnterAs.this,UI_Main_Worker.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
        Log.d("bantai", "onStart: after phonenumber");
        startActivity(new Intent(EnterAs.this, UI_Main_User.class));
        finish();
    } else {
        Log.d("bantai", "onStart: no auth");
        user_ib.setClickable(true);
        worker_ib.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use [getProviderData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-abstract-list-extends-userinfo-getproviderdata-) on the user object to determine which authentication providers are used for that user.  Each [UserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) object exposes the provider through its [getProviderId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo#getProviderId()) method.

Comment: I have tried getProviderData() and getPoviderId() none worked please help